# Convert sql statement into flask_sqlalchemy with pagination

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I want to convert this statement into Flask-Sqlalchemy equivalent with pagination.

```sql
SELECT * FROM file JOIN course_files ON file.id == course_files.file_id JOIN course_students ON course_students.course_id = course_files.course_id and course_students.user_id = 1
```

Where the user_id could vary.

I have tried below query but it doesn't filter by the user id for unknown reasons

```py
db.session.query(File).join(course_files).join(
        course_students, (
                course_students.c.course_id == course_files.c.course_id and
                course_students.c.user_id == 1
        )).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the answer.

```py
db.session.query(File
).join(
         course_files, File.id == course_files.c.file_id
).join(
         course_students, course_students.c.course_id == course_files.c.course_id
).filter(
         course_students.c.user_id == current_user.id
).paginate(current_page, per_page, errors_out=False)
```